# Grid filter on inherited projection DAC

Tags: filter, grid, acumatica, projection, dac

I created an inherited projection and it's working fine but for some reason I cannot use the grid filter options.

I can sort but I can't filter. When I filter I get the message "The multi-part identifier "FAAccrualTranCst.PONbr" could not be bound."

Here is my inherited projection including APTran and I decorated it with the **[PXSubstitute(GraphType = typeof(AssetGLTransactions))]**

```
    [Serializable]
    [PXProjection(typeof(Select2<GLTran, 
        LeftJoin<FAAccrualTran, On<GLTran.tranID, Equal<tranID>>,
            LeftJoin<APTran, On<GLTran.refNbr,Equal<APTran.refNbr>,
                And<GLTran.tranType,Equal<APTran.tranType>,
                    And<GLTran.branchID,Equal<APTran.branchID>>>>>>, 
        Where<GLTran.module, NotEqual<BatchModule.moduleFA>, And<GLTran.released, Equal<True>>>>), new Type[] { typeof(FAAccrualTran) })]
    [PXSubstitute(GraphType = typeof(AssetGLTransactions))]
public partial class FAAccrualTranCst : FAAccrualTran
{
    public abstract class pONbr : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    [PXDBString(25, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">aaaaaaaaaa", BqlField = typeof(APTran.pONbr))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "PONbr")]
    public virtual string PONbr { get; set; }
}
```

I created an inherited DAC from a projection and I expect to use the grid filter on the new added fields.

Answer (score 0):

Should you join to FAAccrualTranCst instead of FAAccrualTran in your projection?

Comment: Not sure if I follow you, do you have a sample?

Comment: [PXProjection(typeof(Select2<GLTran, 
        LeftJoin<FAAccrualTranCst, On<GLTran.tranID, Equal<tranID>>,

Comment: It didn't work.